# Custom ROM targeted for children

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, data-monitoring

Is there a custom ROM that is targeted at child users? I would be interested in features such as:

- custom screens per child
- restricted app usage (installing, removing, screen/usage time, blocking in app purchases)
- usage monitoring/logging
- geo location

Comment: Please see [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)